# AttributeError references a non imported package

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and I am running into the following problem, it's driving me nuts.

I'm trying to subtract two dates using the datetime package but one of the 2 dates is a string value given by the user via an `input()` and the other one is a date given by `datetime.date.today()`.

So I use `datetime.strptime(answer, '%Y-%m-%d').date()` to convert the string value into a date, I then do the subtraction I wanted to do and print the result, but it looks like this: `15 days, 0:00:00`.

I wanted to remove , `0:00:00` so I tried to use the `.replace()` function to remove it but when I ran the code I got this error back:`AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

I have imported the timedelta module at some point but I didn't need it in the end so I removed the line of code where I imported it. I don't understand why I still get an error that references timedelta.

Could anyone explain to me what is happening ? And possibly how to solve the problem ? Thank you very much !

I've already tried using `del timedelta` and rewriting my code in a new file and a new directory and even in another IDE but the error never goes away.

Here's my code:

```
import datetime

current_date = datetime.date.today()
answer = input('Enter a date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')

from datetime import datetime

new_end_date = datetime.strptime(answer, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
days_added = new_end_date - current_date


print(type(days_added))
print(days_added.replace(', 0:00:00', ''))
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. _I don't understand why I still get an error that references timedelta._ The issue is exactly what is says, you're trying to access an attribute `replace` on an object which doesn't have that attribute. You're printing the type of `days_added`, too, so I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. In python, a minus(`-`) operation between two `datetime.datetime` object product a `datetime.timedelta` object.

So `days_added` always is a `datetime.timedelta` object. and a `datetime.timedelta` is not a string, so it doesn't have a `replace` method.

if you want to remove ", 0:00:00", convert `datetime.timedelta` object to string first.

Use `str(days_added)` first, and you will have no error

Comment: Hey, I figured it out yesterday night a few hours after I posted this, I used the type() method to check the class type of my variables and finally solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help nonetheless !